# Trying to override onbeforeunload in first step of form wizard

Tags: jquery

This pertains to a form wizard with 5 steps, I don't want the user to hit back and lose form data in any step 2-4. I have added a flag for the submit function and need to add this one for the first step. If they get there by accident and try and leave I dont want the cofirm dialog popping up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var action_is_post = false;
    $("form").submit(function () {
    action_is_post = true;
 });

//this is the trouble spot. on the first step the "navigation" of the form has a class 
//of current (on step one = current)
$(this).ready(function () {
if ($("#stepDesc0").is(".current")) {
action_is_post = true;    
}
);   

window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
if (!action_is_post)
return 'Using the browsers back, refresh or close button will cause you to lose all
form data. Please use the Next and Back buttons on the form.';
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not following here, are you saying `$("#stepDesc0").is(".current")` is false when it should be true?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's where Im getting screwed up here. how would I make it true? I applied it the same way I did for the submit function, which works. Or so I think? I need it to be true so it will override the onbeforeunload function

Answer (score 0):

The variable `action_is_post` is declared local to `$(document).ready()` and it is in a different scope when it reaches the function `confirmExit()`. Therefore it is undefined and hence false in the conditional. Try adding the declaration outside the `$(document).ready()` as shown below:

```
var action_is_post = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function () {
    action_is_post = true;
});
```

This makes the variable global and it should behave the way that you expect.

---

**EDIT:** I checked the code in your page and it is very convoluted and difficult to follow. My recommendation is to simply run the comparison checking for the class in your `confirmExit()` function again, instead of checking the value of the `action_is_post` variable.

```
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    if (!$("#stepDesc0").hasClass(".current"))
      return 'Using the browsers back, refresh or close .....';
  }
```

Comment: That makes sense, but still not working.
http://www.kinetick.com/FOO/purchase
if you have a minute, Id greatly appreciate the help getting this working.

Comment: I still need it to apply to the submit function, the user should be able to close/refresh/back button/etc on the first and final step

Comment: Added your code, still performs onbeforeunload on all steps, almost like its not grabbing the class "current" when viewed in firebug, it shows ul#steps li.current, so I know it has that property.